# FOR XML PATH and xsi:nil attributes

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql, for-xml, for-xml-path

Good morning all,

I have a large query utilising FOR XML PATH to output a .xml file.I have the main select which basically just represents the root ie

```
select *
from tbl
for xml path ('root'),elements xsinil
```

I then have subsequent nested selects within this main select i.e.

```
select 
    (
        select null [level1],
               '2'  [level2]
        from tbl
        for xml path('nested1'),type
    ),
    (
        select null [level1],
               '2'  [level2]
        from tbl
        for xml path('nested2'),type
    )
for xml path('root'),elements xsinil
```

However, the element xsinil argument placed on the for xml path does not have any affect on the contained subqueries i.e. the Level1 element is just a closed tag. I need this to display as xsi:nil="true".

I can achieve this through adding elements xsinil argument to the for xml path statement e.g.

```
for xml path('nested1'),type,elements xsinil
```

The problem with this is that the namespace declaration gets repeated at the subquery level.

I can find plenty of examples of using elements xsinil but none where it is to apply to a subquery without a repeated namesapce declaration.

To confirm, I am looking for the following output:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <nested1>
    <level1 xsi:nil="true">
    <level2>2</level2>
  </nested1>
  <nested2>
    <level1 xsi:nil="true">
    <level2>2</level2>
  </nested2>
</root>
```

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to prevent this behavior with subqueries using `for xml path`. There is a similar issue reported here. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements

You can get the output you want if you  use `for xml explicit` instead.

```
declare @T table(Level1 int, Level2 int)
insert into @T values(null, 2)

select 1    as Tag,
       null as Parent,
       null as [root!1],
       null as [nested1!2!level1!ELEMENTXSINIL],
       null as [nested1!2!level2!ELEMENTXSINIL],
       null as [nested2!3!level1!ELEMENTXSINIL],
       null as [nested2!3!level2!ELEMENTXSINIL]
union all
select 2    as Tag,
       1    as Parent,
       null,
       Level1,
       Level2,
       null,
       null
from @T       
union all
select 3    as Tag,
       1    as Parent,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       Level1,
       Level2
from @T       
for xml explicit
```

Result:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <nested1>
    <level1 xsi:nil="true" />
    <level2>2</level2>
  </nested1>
  <nested2>
    <level1 xsi:nil="true" />
    <level2>2</level2>
  </nested2>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I think you are right in that it is not possible using subqueries. I have, as a result, changed the way the preceeding queries build the data so that the creation of the .xml does not require subqueries. I am going to mark your answer as correct as it does work - my client just wants to avoid the use of for xml explicit. Thanks