# Using SQL Server “FOR XML”: Convert Result to text

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get a result of FOR XML query as a text.
I've found some similar question here: 
[Using SQL Server "FOR XML": Convert Result Datatype to Text/varchar/string whatever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655332/using-sql-server-for-xml-convert-result-datatype-to-text-varchar-string-whate) 
but in my case I use WITH XMLNAMESPACES statement and this solution doesnt work for me.
How can I get a result of this following query as a text?

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:blablablabla' as bi) 
SELECT 'urn:blablabla.xsd' AS "@xsi:schemaLocation",  

        (SELECT 'aaaa' AS 'bi:idValue', 
                'bbbb' AS 'bi:idContext' 
        FOR XML PATH('bi:Part1'),TYPE), 

        (SELECT 'cccc' AS 'bi:idValue', 
                'dddd' AS 'bi:idContext' 
        FOR XML PATH('bi:Part2'),TYPE) 
 FOR XML PATH('bi:Items'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

Thanks

---

The result should look like this:

```
<bi:Items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bi="urn:blablablabla" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:blablabla.xsd">
<bi:Part1 xmlns:bi="urn:blablablabla">
 <bi:idValue>aaaa</bi:idValue>
 <bi:idContext>bbbb</bi:idContext>
</bi:Part1>
<bi:Part2 xmlns:bi="urn:blablablabla">
 <bi:idValue>cccc</bi:idValue>
 <bi:idContext>dddd</bi:idContext>
</bi:Part2>
</bi:Items
```

My goal is to get this result as a text and not as XML datatype.
For example to do something like that:

```
DECLARE @ResultText NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @ResultText = ... Returned text from this query ...
```

In addition maybe you know how can I avoid repeating of namespace in each node?

Thank you

Comment: what should the output from you example look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `select` instead of `set`.

```
DECLARE @ResultText NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:blablablabla' as bi) 
SELECT @ResultText = 
  (
    SELECT 'urn:blablabla.xsd' AS "@xsi:schemaLocation",  

            (SELECT 'aaaa' AS 'bi:idValue', 
                    'bbbb' AS 'bi:idContext' 
            FOR XML PATH('bi:Part1'),TYPE), 

            (SELECT 'cccc' AS 'bi:idValue', 
                    'dddd' AS 'bi:idContext' 
            FOR XML PATH('bi:Part2'),TYPE) 
     FOR XML PATH('bi:Items'), ELEMENTS XSINIL 
);
```

**Update:**

> avoid repeating of namespace

According to these two answers there is a way to do it with `for xml explicit`.

[FOR XML PATH and xsi:nil attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6453217/569436)
[How do I remove redundant namespace in nested query when using FOR XML PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3244491/569436)

If you want the behavior to change for the future you can vote on this connect item.
[suppress namespace attributes in nested SELECT FOR XML statements](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements)

Comment: You are welcome. If this worked you should consider accepting this answer using the tick-mark to the right. It will show the community that this question has been answered.

Comment: Yes, It works, but maybe somebody knows how to avoid repeating of namespace in each node...

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that one. I don't know how to do it but I will update my answer if I figure it out.